# Spring security onAuthenticationSuccess java config , repository access-> null

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using spring4 and spring security, spring data jpa, spring boot. I need to do some processing(eg. save some data into session) after successful user authentication. So my code:

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Autowired UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("attribute1",userService.findBySomething() );
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.formLogin().successHandler(new MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
   }

//another methods ..
}
```

after caling userService.findBySomething()  getting :
java.lang.NullPointerException: null    at org.pckg.MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java:40)
When I call this userService.findBySomething() in other place eg controller, then call is succesful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I solve that issue. Instead of

```
    http.formLogin().successHandler(new MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
```

inject authenticationsuccesshandler through dependency injection:

```
    @Autowired MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler myAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    http.formLogin().successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add the attributes in your main view controller after spring security has finished the authentication process and redirects the user to your main page?

Edit:  You show code autowiring in your user repository, but in the code you're accessing your userService.  Assuming you're showing all of your code, you need to autowire in your userService object as well.

Comment: It's JSON rest backend, it's possible to acces into different urls, there isn't something like "home url". I think it's common to put this type of data into place after succesfull login in different frameworks, but it looks really pain do that in spring security.